# Is there a way in magento to detect if an address already exists

Tags: php, magento, magento-1.7

Is there any way in magento to detect if an address already exists.

The customer can decide - in the OnePageCheckout - if he want to use an existing address or enter a new one. 
If it is an existing one i don't want to / need to validate it.

So is there any way to find out if it's a new address or not?

Answer (score 1):

You can get full list of loged customer adresses, by using this code:

```
$customer = Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->getCustomer();
foreach ($customer->getAddresses() as $address) {
    Zend_Debug::dump($address->debug());
}
```

Comment: This doesn't answer the question, he is asking if there is a way to check if an address is the same compared to an existing one of the same customer.